# Custom SXA Rendering displaying Incorrect Data Source

Tags: sxa, caching

I've built out a custom SXA component by cloning an existing component, creating a custom Controller/Repository/View and updating the template. The template has 3 fields on it, a Checkbox, a Droplist, and a Multilist with Search (to allow searching for and selecting a blog article).

Where I'm running into an issue is with the rendering seemingly holding on to the wrong data source. I'll try to explain as best I can.

I have created two data sources which are pointing at two different items in the Multilist field

**Data Source 1 (Article 1 is selected from the multilist)**

**Data Source 2 (Article 2 is selected from the multilist)**

Within my site I have two pages I would like to use this rendering on.

**Page 1**

**Page 2**

**On Page 1, I add the component/rendering to the page and select the data source (Data Source 1)**

**On Page 2, I add the component/rendering to the page and select the data source (Data Source 2)**

I load up Page 1 and everything looks good, I see Article 1 data displayed. I then load up Page 2, and this is when I start seeing the issue. Page 2, which is using Data Source 2, is showing the data from Data Source 1. Debugging through the Repository code I see that the Rendering.DataSourceItem is Data Source 1. I cleared cache thinking something was cached, and that didn't change anything. I reset my app pool, still no change. Another odd thing is that if I change the Article of the data source, that both pages are displaying, and publish the change I don't see that change reflected when debugging. If I restart my computer or reset IIS completely and then, as a test load up page 2 first, I then see Data Source 2 displayed. But, if I then load up page 1 it now shows Data Source 2.

I've checked and there are no irregular cache settings on the rendering which might explain this.

Has anybody encountered this before?

Thanks

Comment: Can you check if Cacheable checkbox is checked since you are seeing DataSource 1 content only ? You can check this on individual presentation setting as well as rendering level setting.

Comment: @Verdroon I've noticed such issue with Sitecore 9.3 Custom Page List component. Did you find any solution?

Comment: What is the value on `lifetime=` in the custom component `<register>` configuration?